# Strangest thing I ever seen Java/Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I have a very strange problem

My controller reads a `String[] paramDescriptions`

It reads well unless the sent in the ajax has size 1. If it has size 1 I'm not getting any value.

```js
var paramDescriptions = [];


var paramDescriptionInputs = $('input[name="paramDescriptions"]');
$(paramDescriptionInputs).each(function(index, val) {
  paramDescriptions.push($(val).val());
});

console.log(paramDescriptions);


 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("paramDescriptions", paramDescriptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1> 2 values or more works </h1>


<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for EXPECTED_RATE_VALUE" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName1">


<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for EXPECTED_RATE_VALUE" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName2">

<h1> 1 doesn't </h1>


<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for EXPECTED_RATE_VALUE" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName3">
```

Backend

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadTestCase(@RequestParam(value = "paramDescriptions", required = false) String[] paramDescriptions) {
    System.out.println(paramDescriptions);
}
```

Comment: If I add `paramDescriptions.push("");` under `paramDescriptions.push($(val).val());` it now sends 2 correctly. wth

Comment: it's like the java spring doesn't know there's a string[] being sent

Comment: **I found the problem but i dont know the solution**. The problem is sending `[""]`